# FB.init gives 'root undefined' or 'innerHTML' error

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have written a Facebook website app that gives the possibility to push reactions that people give to news items to there Facebook wall. Everything works fine except in IE8.

When I visit the homepage with IE9 compatibility mode IE8 I get:

```
Unable to set value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined
```

When  visit with authentic IE8 I get:

```
'root' is null or not an object
```

This is the Facebook code I have on that page:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
FB.init({
    appId  : '${siteConfiguration.facebookAppId}',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});
</script>
```

I have tried putting the script tags in the  and the fb-root in the  but I still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was right in front of me!

```
FB quote: The best place to put this code is right before the closing </body> tag.
```

I placed it in the <head> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you need to reorder your  code put the line
     
afer

so your code now will be

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

 <script>
FB.init({
appId  : '${siteConfiguration.facebookAppId}',
status : true, // check login status
cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});
</script>
```